# Angular to .Net GET request: Header added on client side missing on server

Tags: angular, request, header, cors

I have an angular client sending a request:

```
this.http
    .get<any>(`https://localhost:4200/api/General`, {
      headers: { 'UserID': '0'}
    })
```

I'm expecting this header on the core 5 server side, but

```
context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("UserID")
```

returns false

I also have CORS settings:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CORSpolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

and:

```
app.UseCors("CORSpolicy");
```

In chrome browser I see that header is sent:

> Provisional headers are shown Learn more Accept: application/json,
> text/plain, */* DNT: 1 Referer: http://localhost:4200/ sec-ch-ua:
> "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows" User-Agent:
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 **UserID: 0**

How to get this header on the server side? Who is blocking it?

Answer (score -1):

I found a problem. I tried to get a header in middleware, but middleware in a startup was registered before UseCORS. Registering middleware after UseCORS fixed the problem